# Discrepancy between text's answer and mine: singular points of $\cot\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) - \frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, singularity

The points $\frac{1}{k\pi}$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ are all singularities of the function $f(z) = \cot\left(\frac{1}{z} \right) - \frac{1}{z}$.

My textbook seems to think that they are simple poles of $f(z)$, but for any $z = \frac{1}{k \pi}$, the limit d.n.e. (we get $\infty$ approaching along the positive real axis, and $-\infty$ approaching along the negative real axis). According to a theorem I have on the classification of singular points, if $z_{0}$ is an isolated singular point of $f(z)$ and $\lim_{z \to z_{0}}f(z)$ does not exists, then $z_{0}$ is an essential singularity.

So, I would argue that the $\frac{1}{k\pi}$ are essential singular points, and not poles.

Who is right? Me or the book? And why?

Comment: If you're still skeptical, you might be able to write out the Laurent series of cotangent near the poles and verify this.

Comment: if (from any direction) $\lim_{z \to z_0} |f(z)| = \infty$ and $f(z)$ is holomorphic on  $0 < |z-z_0| < \epsilon$, then $z_0$ is a pole, i.e. there exists an integer $k$ such that $(z-z_0)^k f(z)$ is holomoprhic on $|z-z_0| < \epsilon$. it is a very important theorem that you should prove right now  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is right. The correct statement is that $z_0$ is a pole of $f$ if and only if $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0} f(z) = \infty$ in the *extended complex plane*, which is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0} |f(z)| = \infty$.

Comment: but if, say it approached $\infty$ from one side and $0$ from the other, that would still be essential, right?

Comment: Yes. I think that by far the best way to understand this material is to look at Laurent series expansions centered at the singular points in question. In particular, it's not sufficient to look just on the axes in order to see what the limit is. You must be sure you approach $\infty$ in every possible way of approaching $z_0$.

Comment: true. But more often than not you can tell if a limit doesn't exist if you get disparate things approaching along axes.